# Why would downcase the key of has not work in this case?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to play with the `Hash` class. Here is my approach on downcasing the keys of a hash:

```
myhash.map { |k, v| k.downcase, v }
```

but I get:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):11: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting '='
```

However, if I do:

```
myhash.map { |k, v| [k.downcase, v] }
```

It gets correctly downcased, even though it is inside an array. Why doesn't it let me just do

```
myhash.map { |k, v| k.downcase, v }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map wants to do the operation on each pair and return 1 value.

When you use [] it is returning one value - an array.  When you use k.downcase, v it can do the k.downcase part, but then it doesn't know what `, v` means. It's confused about trying to have a result of two things when it should be one.  When those are inside the `[]` (array) brackets they are just elements of the one array that is returned.
`

Comment: thanks for the answer. but when using [], why do I get [["key", "value"]]. Why two arrays?

Answer (score 1):

`#map` uses the Class' `#each` method to iterate, `Hash` yields two values with `#each` (The key and the value at each position). The result of each, however, is necessarily an Array. Luckily there is a method for turning Arrays back into Hashes.

If you want to be able to downcase keys you can utilise the zipped-array-to-Hash conversion method `Hash[]`:

```
Hash[myhash.map { |k, v| [k.downcase, v] }]
```

That will give you the answer that you want.

Comment: Why is the result of each 'necessarily' an array?

Comment: "The Enumerable mixin provides collection classes with several traversal and searching methods, and with the ability to sort. `The class must provide a method each, which yields successive members of the collection.`" http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html

Answer (score 0):

The return value of a block would be the return value of the last expression in it. That means that it has to be a Ruby object. `k.downcase, v` is not a Ruby object. Whatever the specification of a particular method is, that would be syntactically wrong.

Particularly, `map` method takes the return value of the block for each iteration, and put them in an array. If you want some construct that retains the information of the keys and the values of a hash, at least, you have to return a single object that holds the information of both a key and its value. An array containing them i.e., `[k.downcase, v]` is a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message. You have a `SyntaxError`. Your code isn't even syntactically valid. It won't even compile, let alone run. `downcase` doesn't even enter into the picture.

```
foo, bar
```

is not a valid Ruby expression, this has nothing to do with `Hash` or `downcase`. You will also get a `SyntaxError` if you just try something like the following:

```
1, 1
```